# Phabricator Audit got Exception (Can't parse an empty diff)

Tags: svn, phabricator, post-commit

I just set up a Phabricator using svn and I want it to work with post-commit. actually it work well after any one commit a change. [this is a snapshot of the Audit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEAtI.jpg)

but when i click one commit and there is an exception:Can't parse an empty diff.
did I missing something when setting up?
[this is a snapshot of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iWBb.jpg)

why? why?why? can anyone help me out?

Comment: any one else helping?